# Data of addview cannot appeared in linearLayout of scrollview

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am trying to applying tutorial,
this a dummy store app, I showing the data that added from user inside view then added it in linear layout of scrollview, the app is run fine and the data is added to viewmodel I see it in the log but I failed to diplay it in the view and I don't know what the problem is

[image]

The code of model class

```
@Parcelize
data class Shoe(
    var name: String, var size: Double, var company: String, var description: String,
    val images: List<String> = mutableListOf()
) : Parcelable
```

**MainViewModel**

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _shoesList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Shoe>>()
    val shoesList: LiveData<MutableList<Shoe>>
        get() = _shoesList

    fun addShoe(shoe: Shoe) {
        _shoesList.value?.add(shoe)
    }

    init {
        Timber.tag(TAG).i(": MainViewModel created")
        val testShoe1 = Shoe("Test Shoe 1",

            47.0, "dummy shoe company", "Dummy shoe description")
        val testShoe2 = Shoe("Test Shoe 2",
            40.0, "dummy shoe company", "Dummy shoe description")


        _shoesList.value?.add(testShoe1)
        _shoesList.value?.add(testShoe2)
    }


}
```

**fragment_shoe_list layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/shoeListLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.ShoeListFragment">


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/shoeListLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </ScrollView>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/button_add_shoe" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**ShoeListFragment class**

```
class ShoeListFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentShoeListBinding

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private lateinit var showRowBinding: ShoeRowLayoutBinding

    private val TAG = "ShoeListFragment"

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.fragment_shoe_list, container, false)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mainViewModel.shoesList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            it.forEach { shoe ->

                Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: ${it.toString()}")
                
                Timber.tag(TAG).i("test shoe ${shoe.name}")

                showRowBinding = ShoeRowLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)


                showRowBinding.newShoe = shoe

                binding.shoeListLinearLayout.addView(showRowBinding.root)
            }
        }

        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            Timber.i(mainViewModel.shoesList.value?.joinToString(separator = "\n"))
            findNavController().navigate(ShoeListFragmentDirections.actionShoeListFragmentToDetailsFragment())
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_details layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="mainViewModel"
            type="com.udacity.shoestore.models.MainViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="shoeData"
            type="com.udacity.shoestore.models.Shoe" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.DetailsFragment">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shoeNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/shoe_name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/shoeNameED"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/shoeNameED"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/shoeNameED" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Company Name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/companyNameED"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/companyNameED"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/companyNameED" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shoeSizeTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Shoe Size"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/shoeSizeED"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/shoeSizeED"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/shoeSizeED" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Description"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/descriptionED"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/descriptionED"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.007"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/descriptionED" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/saveButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
            android:text="Save"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shoeSizeED" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/shoeNameED"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="@={shoeData.name}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/descriptionED"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="@={shoeData.description}"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/companyNameED" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/companyNameED"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="@={shoeData.company}"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shoeNameED" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/shoeSizeED"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="@={`` + shoeData.size}"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descriptionED" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**FragmentDetails Class**

```
class DetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentDetailsBinding

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        binding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.fragment_details, container, false)

        binding.mainViewModel = mainViewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this


        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
//        binding.mainViewModel = this.mainViewModel

        binding.saveButton.setOnClickListener {

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.shoeNameED.text.toString())) {
                binding.shoeNameED.error = "required text"
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.shoeSizeED.text.toString())) {
                binding.shoeSizeED.error = "required text"
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.companyNameED.text.toString())) {
                binding.companyNameED.error = "required text"
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.descriptionED.text.toString())) {
                binding.descriptionED.error = "required text"
            } else {

                val newShoe = Shoe(
                    name = binding.shoeNameED.text.toString(),
                    size = binding.shoeSizeED.text.toString().toDouble(),
                    company = binding.companyNameED.text.toString(),
                    description = binding.descriptionED.text.toString()
                )
                binding.shoeData = newShoe

                Timber.tag(TAG).i(newShoe.toString())

                mainViewModel.addShoe(newShoe)

                findNavController().navigate(DetailsFragmentDirections.actionDetailsFragmentToShoeListFragment())
            }

        }

    }
}
```

and finally this a row layout that should inflated and added to the scrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="newShoe"
            type="com.udacity.shoestore.models.Shoe" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/company_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Company: "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name: "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/size_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Size: "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/company_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description: "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/size_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/size_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@{newShoe.description}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/desc_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/size_text" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/size_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@{Double.toString(newShoe.size)}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/size_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@{newShoe.name}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/company_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@{newShoe.company}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/company_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_text" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few potential issues I can see, I don't know which is causing the problem here, but you can take a look at both!

Firstly, when you add an item in your `ViewModel`, you're doing this:

```
fun addShoe(shoe: Shoe) {
    _shoesList.value?.add(shoe)
}
```

But your `LiveData` doesn't contain an initial value:

```
private val _shoesList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Shoe>>()
```

So there's no value, no list to `add` to. Since you're null-checking `value` that line is going to fail silently. You said you're adding shoes to the VM, and you can see them in the log, but the code you posted won't do that.

---

The second issue is that even if you have an initial empty list, what that `addShoe` function does is get a reference to the current `List` held in that `LiveData`, and then changing its contents. The `LiveData` itself *doesn't know anything has changed*, so it won't push an update to its observers. Depending on what's going on with your Fragments, if they're not being recreated it's possible they're just not seeing any observer updates, so they're not displaying anything new.

You can fix that by setting `value` on the `LiveData` again. You can just hand it the current value, it's the *setting* that's important. That way it will notify all the observers:

```
// create an empty list as the initial value
private val _shoesList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Shoe>>(mutableListOf())

fun addShoe(shoe: Shoe) {
    // one of the few places I recommend using !!, when you know you'll always have a value set
    val list = _shoesList.value!!.add(shoe)
    // or you could do
    // val list = (_shoesList.value ?: mutableListOf<Shoe>()).add(shoe)
    _shoesList.value = list
}
```

---

But honestly, using a `MutableList` can cause problems, because the data can change silently in the background as the list is modified - if any of your observers are using the last list value you passed (which is actually *the same list*) then you're changing the data they hold, and that can break things that compare the "new list" you pass to the "old list" - changes disappear because they're identical, because they're *the same object*.

It's cleaner to just use immutable lists:

```
// use an immutable List, with an empty version as the start value
private val _shoesList = MutableLiveData<List<Shoe>>(emptyList())

fun addShoe(shoe: Shoe) {
    // updating is as simple as making a new list
    _shoesList.value = _shoesList.value!! + shoe
}
```

and that takes care of your updating, pushing a new value, and since it's a new list every time it won't affect the old lists you pushed earlier (unless you edit the `Shoe` objects themselves of course)

---

And lastly if you're going to be adding view to your `LinearLayout`, you probably want to use the `inflate` method that takes the parent `View`, so it can be inflated to the correct size (e.g. it needs to know what size `match_parent` actually works out as):

```
showRowBinding = ShoeRowLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, binding.shoeListLinearLayout, false)
```

Or you could try making that last parameter `true` to attach it to that parent directly (which you're doing with `addView`)

Comment: thank you for detailed instruction, Just there's one problem I couldn't figure it, I am trying to add initial dummy data to the shoe list, like mention above `val testShoe1 = Shoe( "Test Shoe 1", 47.0, "dummy shoe company", "Dummy shoe description"`
the user can show it at first row, then when added the new value the second view added below it, then the third and so on, the problem is If I inflated the row layout then I added it to the linear layout of scroll view and after that inside for loop when user try to add a new values I got this error

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` so If I added inital values I cannot added new values, and If I leave it empty and let the user added value when app running the new row view replced old one, (it's not added below it inside ScrollView),  I tried many methods like NestedScrollView with linearlayout, ScrollView with realtiveLayout, etc but all my tries fails, I am not sure If I sucess to explain the problem for you or not

Comment: please take look at `fragment_shoe_list layout` and `ShoeListFragment class` and  the row layout in my question

Comment: @IndianaEvans that error means you're calling `addView(someView)` when you've already added `someView` to a parent view. So it's telling you to `remove` it from that parent first. If you're doing what I said with the `inflate` call, and using `true` for the last parameter (`attachToRoot`), that *adds* it to the parent - you don't need to call `addView` after that (and if you do you'll get an error like this - the view's already attached). By the way, it would be better to use a `RecyclerView` (or `ListView` if you really want) since you're making a list here. More setup but worth learning!

Comment: I already know about listview and recyclerview and how to implement it but in this project exmple above they required from us to use ScrollView or NastedScroll view and add view to it when the user added new values, I tried the soultion you provided and changed the value of it to true , onCreateView I added this line `showRowBinding = ShoeRowLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, true)` but the app is crashed directly

Comment: I got this erorr `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.udacity.shoestore:layout/shoe_row_layout: Views added to a FragmentContainerView must be associated with a Fragment. View androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{d7b8f91 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} is not associated with a Fragment.
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Views added to a FragmentContainerView must be associated with a Fragment. View androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{d7b8f91 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} is not associated with a Fragment.`

Comment: @IndianaEvans you're passing `container` into the the `inflate` call, which I'm guessing is the Fragment's `container` that you get in `onCreateView` (probably a `FragmentContainerView` in your Activity). Your items are supposed to go in the `LinearLayout` inside your `ScrollView`, right? That's the parent you need to pass to the `inflate` call - look at the code I posted

Comment: yes it was container fragment, I changed it to linearlayout and it's worked like you said I don't need to call `addView` if I set the lst parm to true but, this way would not add the view like a list, it's just replce the values with new values that added by the user

Comment: @IndianaEvans oh right yeah, it would replace them I suppose! Well make sure you make that `inflate` call anyway, with the correct `parent` and `attachToRoot` as *false*, so your view is the correct size for that parent when you do `addView`